# Associating terms in dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list,

```
liste= ['maison_NOUN belle_QUALIF', 'maison_NOUN belle_QUALIF et_CCONJ jolie_ADJ', 'maison_NOUN 
 grande_ADJ' , "jardin_NOUN belle_ADJ"]
```

I want to have this output :

```
 {"maison": ["belle", "jolie", "grande"] , "jardin": ["belle"]
```

the output must satisfy this condition:

```
{"NOUN" : [QUALIF or ADJ] }   # and taking into account NOUN like "maison" that have multiple attributes  (remove duplicates)
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far? It's also not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please explain how you get from your input to the output (what are the rules here) and why did you mention the "we must have". It's very unclear. Also, please write your code / attempts so we can help you with wherever you are stuck in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a `dict` comprehension:

```
liste = ['maison_NOUN belle_QUALIF', 'maison_NOUN belle_QUALIF et_CCONJ jolie_ADJ', 'maison_NOUN grande_ADJ' , "jardin_NOUN belle_ADJ"]
dct = {s.split()[0].split('_')[-1]: [s.split()[-1].split('_')[-1]] for s in liste}
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'NOUN': ['ADJ']}
```

Lets break it down:

1. Here is the most basic conversion from a `list` to a `dict` using a `dict` comprehension:

```
dct = {s: s for s in liste}
```

Where the `dict` has each element of the `list` as a key and value.

2. Since you want the value to be a list, add square brackets to the value part of the `dict` comprehension:

```
dct = {s: [s] for s in liste}
```

3. I see that for the key, you need the word on the right side of the underscore of the first chunk of characters of each string.
   First, to get the first chunk of characters, use `.split()` to return a list of all the chunks of characters separated by a space,
   and use the indice `0` to get the first chunk. Then, split the first chunk by the underscore using `.split('_'), and use the indice` -1` to get the last element of the returned list of words:

```
dct = {s.split()[0].split('_')[-1]: [s] for s in liste}
```

4. For the value, the same logic applies, but this time, we want the last chunk of characters
   separated by a space, instead of the first chunk:

```
dct = {s.split()[0].split('_')[-1]: [s.split()[-1].split('_')[-1]] for s in liste}
```